# Iterate folders in a weblink with python

Tags: python, python-requests

I would like to browse through a web link and get the max dated folder in there.
For each folder I would then like to iterate through all the files and get the max dated file in there. Is there an easy way to do this?
web link has folders like
2017
2016
2015

Inside each year dated folder like 2017 there are excel files.
I need to read the folder 2017 as that was the latest created folder and then iterate into that and read the latest timestamp file.

```
try:
    url = "http://<url>/path"

    def find_files(url):

        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml")

        hrefs = []

        for a in soup.find_all('a'):
            hrefs.append(a['href'])

        return hrefs

    list_of_links = find_files(url)


    ## show what you've found:
    for link in list_of_links:
        if "?" not in link:
            inner_url = url + "/" + link
            inner_list = find_files(inner_url)
            print inner_list
```

I tried this code but im not sure how I can get the timestamp of folders and then get the latest folder and then iterate through that.
This also gives me ?C=N, paths which I want to ignore
Also im not sure how to do this recursively

Comment: please add some code to set the context and a pseudo example

Comment: no one has any insight into how I can make this work?

Comment: [Edit] your Question and explain/show what did you get from the first `request`? Show the first 10 Lines of `soup `.